# Catching (eof-)exception of istream ignore

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, eof, istream

I've got a little problem. I want to skip some lines in a file. Atm I am using

```
        for(int i=0; i < ln -1; ++i)
        {
            ifFile.ignore((std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max)(),'\n');
        }
```

On [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) there is written that ignore will throw an exception if eof is reached. But I can't get it with try/catch. What did I do wrong? Or did I misread sth?

What I need is that I want to start at first line again for some operations if eof is reached.

So I tried sth but it didn't work:

```
        for(int i=0; i < ln -1; ++i)
        {
            try
            {
                ifFile.ignore((std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max)(),'\n');
            }
            catch(exception e)
            {
                if(ifFile.eof())
                {
                    ifFile.clear(ifFile.eofbit);
                    ifFile.seekg(std::ios::beg);
                    _readCounter.currLine = 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

But it didn't run into catch().

If there are some questions feel free to ask.

Corrected one:

```
        for(int i=0; i < ln; i++)
        {
            if(ifFile.ignore((std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max)(),'\n').eof())
            {
                ifFile.clear(ifFile.eofbit);
                ifFile.seekg(std::ios::beg);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have [set the exception mask](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) (as described in [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore))?

Comment: Iostreams don't use exceptions by default, instead they have **failure states**. And it's generally not a good idea to configure an iostream to use exceptions, precisely because of EOF handling. The streams are not really designed for using exceptions for failure reporting.

Comment: but how can I get eofbit, if ignore (should) set at EOF? if(ifFile.eof()) doesn't work directly after ifFile.ignore(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check `eof()` after the call to `ignore()`:

```
if (f.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n').eof()) {
    // end of file was found
}
```